# Is there a way to get Google Analytics ClientID from REST API

Tags: google-analytics

I am on a platform where the JS SDK does not work. I want to try to use the REST API or otherwise to get Google Analytics clientID

With SDK I could use

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

Is there an equivalent REST API? I think measurement protocol does not provide such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rest API because there is no service that provides client ids. This is usually generated by the tracking code.

You can just generate your own clientId with whatever language you have available. UUID format is preferred (to avoid collisions), but basically any (sufficiently random) string works.